# WindowBuilder Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description

Tags: windowbuilder

I've installed the last version (1.9.7) of WindowBuilder.
When i create the "Application Window" i receive the following error

[Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTwER.png)

does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like Eclipse is installed in a location that does not have read or write authority to the locations where WB wants to read or write.

In this case WB tries to read the internal xml description of the swing. What does the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Everything was fine until recently when I switched from windows 7 to windows 10 (not sure if it makes a difference but who knows). I'm kinda newbie in all of this, but I thought it might help if I showed the stack trace. Personally I think the problem might be with the java path if that makes any sense. I remember that I did something when I installed for the first time (university, professor showed us what to do, but I can't remember what it was (some kind of pathing)).

```
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 502 (Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.). javax.swing.JFrame
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.createJavaInfo(JavaInfoUtils.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.parser.ParseFactory.getRootContext(ParseFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4779)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.JavaExceptionComposite.doRefresh(JavaExceptionComposite.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Caused by:

 java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.String javax.swing.JFrame.paramString() accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens javax.swing" to unnamed module @38c6f088
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.appendPropertyComponents(ReflectionUtils.java:1560)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(ReflectionUtils.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.rules.StandardBeanPropertiesRule.begin(StandardBeanPropertiesRule.java:47)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1563)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1387)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2726)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:389)
    ... 56 more




Full context stack trace:

org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 502 (Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.). javax.swing.JFrame
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.createJavaInfo(JavaInfoUtils.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.parser.ParseFactory.getRootContext(ParseFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4779)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.JavaExceptionComposite.doRefresh(JavaExceptionComposite.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Caused by:
 
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.String javax.swing.JFrame.paramString() accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens javax.swing" to unnamed module @38c6f088
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.appendPropertyComponents(ReflectionUtils.java:1560)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(ReflectionUtils.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.rules.StandardBeanPropertiesRule.begin(StandardBeanPropertiesRule.java:47)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1563)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1387)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2726)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:389)
    ... 56 more
```

The code itself doesn't matter, it's same for everything, every time, same error, used codes that worked on my friends PC.

I hope I attached the image correctly.
Thanks on any help :)
If I find the solution, I will post it here :D

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJIUA.png)

Comment: welp, i fixed it... i cant believe that i missed this, but all that i needed to do is to update the window builder nightly build 1.9.8.pre, everything works now :/